# how to completely remove a 3rd-party app?

Tags: applications, install

I have a 3rd-party app that is misbehaving - often crashing as soon as I open it.

It seems like the best approach is to completely remove the app and then re-install it.  So I removed the DMG file (downloaded from the vendor), the app itself, the ~/Library/ApplicationSupport folder, and the ~/Library/Preferences/*plist file - and emptied Trash.   Then re-downloaded the DMG file and re-installed.   So it's the same version of the app as originally installed weeks ago and working fine.  And it still crashes.

There must be some remnant of the app on my machine.   What other app-related files might I need to remove ?  What's a good app to thoroughly uninstall the my app ?

Comment: You don’t identify the app in question, so it’s impossible for anyone to know what files it creates. Even so, the problem could be caused by something else. The first step should be to try to contact the developer for support, if you can. Failing that, you could post a crash report.

Comment: I gather it's considered inappropriate to talk about specific non-Mac apps here.   And it was my hope that there would be common things which might apply to 3rd-party apps in general.    And after some searching, there IS in fact such a thing, which I shall now incorporate into an answer to my question.

Comment: Please be specific about the application you want to uninstall, different applications leave different things behind. Also, this looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) related to your [TurboTax issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467469/how-to-completely-remove-a-3rd-party-app). If TurboTax already crashed after a fresh install, why should it stop crashing after a reinstall?

Comment: Can you edit this to narrow down if the app comes from the Mac App Store and has a standard process to uninstall or if it runs an installer. If it runs an installer - please note if it asks for admin permissions. That case, there's no real way to identify what it did and you are at the mercy of the developer to disclose everything it installed (or you have to re-run the installer and hope you can catch all the things it changes in all the locations it chooses to touch). Thanks for being open to adjusting things and not going off topic potentially.

Comment: Are you still on 12.0.1 [from your earlier question]? That really is the very first step. Initial releases tend to be as buggy as all heck. There have been something like 20 incremental updates since then. Latest is 12.7.2. The developer likely hasn't tested against 12.0.1 in two years.

Comment: I'm at 12.7.2 now, thanks, dunno how I missed that.

Comment: I'm pretty confused, sorry.   My previous question was considered inappropriate because it talked about a specific app, now everyone wants to know what the app is. Yes, it's Turbotax 2023 Desktop for Mac.

Comment: @nohillside It did not crash after a fresh install.   I suspect it crashed because I accidentally slept my machine during an update install.   So I suspected a clean re-install would fix it, which it did, once I figured out how to identify and remove all the system files.

Comment: Please read the answer to https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y to understand why the previous question was put on hold.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, I usually get good results by doing a websearch for "uninstall APPLICATION on macos", this tends to find either the support page of the vendor or a useful web site (sometimes even Ask Different :-)).

Searching for TurboTax specifically leads to [this](https://ttlc.intuit.com/turbotax-support/en-us/help-article/product-delivery/remove-reinstall-turbotax-mac/L6xLWlabw_US_en_US).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly where I found the solution.   Which I generalized, in my answer here, as simply locating ALL the files related to the app by including system files in a Finder search.

Comment: @RustyShackleford There might be files/folders which do not include the name of the application.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is 'fresh up' an app, you often don't need to remove the app itself. Removing prefs & support files should be sufficient.

Firstly, it depends how the app was installed. If it was a simple drag & drop from a .dmg file to Applications, then the simplest way to fresh it up is using something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware). Simply drop the app onto it; it will find all associated system files. Select which to delete - which doesn't have to include the app itself, & let it do its work.

If the app was installed from a package file .pkg, then it is likely to need a dedicated uninstaller.
Sometimes this is included on the original .dmg, sometimes there's one in Application Support, but frequently you will need to find one on the developer's site.

Comment: Indeed, removing all those system files (they were all in ~/Library) probably would've fixed my problem.   Pretty darn flakey piece of software, as I'm pretty sure this all happened because I accidentally slept my machine during an update install.

Comment: There will be files in `/Library`, `~/Library` & `/var` at least. They won't necessarily all contain the app or developer's name. Fairly random example… https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm45g.png

Comment: Good point.   Fortunately in my case they DID all contain the app's name,

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the solution is to remove ANY files on one's machine that are associated with the problematic app, before re-installing it.

Simply using the Finder's search function (cmd-F) to locate files which include some form of the app's name, does not do the trick, because many of these files (that need to be removed) are in the Library.

The way to include those files in your search, and thus be able to remove them, is to include system files in the search.   Click the '+' button in the upper-right corner of Finder's search window, then click 'Other' in the dropdown menu for the criterion to add to the search, and then scroll down to "System Files" and click that.  This hopefully will locate *all* the files that need to be deleted.

This may not always work, because there are apps for which there may be files the names of which don't contain the app or developer's name.